# Rails 5: unable to retrieve hash values from parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm running into a strange issue.

```
undefined method `values' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x007fb06f6b2728>
```

is the error I get, when I assign a variable to a param hash, and try to get it's values.

```
attributes = params[:line_item][:line_item_attributes_attributes] || {}
attributes.values
```

the parameter looks like this a hash of hashes:

```
{"0"=>{"product_attribute_id"=>"4"}, "1"=>{"product_attribute_id"=>"7"}}
```

now when I do this in console and assign that to a variable attributes it works flawlessly. So I'm struggling to understand what isn't working here - and how to make it work.

Comment: this is indeed strange. Any object of class `ActionController::Parameters` should respond to `values`. What are your ruby and rails versions? Could you add a `logger.warn attributes.inspect`?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

take a look to [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html). Very weird since `ActionController::Parameters` is a subclass of Hash, you can convert it [directly](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-to_h) to a hash using the `to_h` method on the params hash.

However `to_h` only will work with whitelisted params, so you can do something like:

```
permitted = params.require(:line_item).permit(: line_item_attributes_attributes)
attributes = permitted.to_h || {}
attributes.values
```

But if instead you do not want to whitelist then you just need to use the `to_unsafe_h` method.

## Update

I was very curious about this issue, so I started researching, and now that you clarified that you are using Rails 5, well that's the cause of this issue, as @tillmo said in stable releases of Rails like 4.x, `ActionController::Parameters` is a subclass of Hash, so it should indeed respond to the `values` method, **however in Rails 5 `ActionController::Parameters` now returns an Object instead of a Hash**

**Note**: this doesn’t affect accessing the keys in the params hash like `params[:id]`. You can view the [Pull Request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/20868) that implemented this change.

To access the parameters in the object you can add `to_h` to the parameters:

`params.to_h`

If we look at the `to_h` method in `ActionController::Parameters` we can see it checks if the parameters are permitted before converting them to a hash.

```
# actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb
def to_h
  if permitted?
    @parameters.to_h
  else
    slice(*self.class.always_permitted_parameters).permit!.to_h
  end
end
```

for example:

```
def do_something_with_params
  params.slice(:param_1, :param_2)
end
```

Which would return:

```
{ :param_1 => "a", :param_2 => "2" }
```

But now that will return an `ActionController::Parameters` object.

Calling `to_h` on this would return an empty hash because param_1 and param_2 aren’t permitted.

To get access to the params from `ActionController::Parameters`, you need to first permit the params and then call `to_h` on the object

```
def do_something_with_params
  params.permit([:param_1, :param_2]).to_h
end
```

The above would return a hash with the params you just permitted, but if you do not want to permit the params and want to skip that step there is another way using `to_unsafe_hash` method:

```
def do_something_with_params
  params.to_unsafe_h.slice(:param_1, :param_2)
end
```

There is a way of always permit the params from a configuration from application.rb, if you want to always allow certain parameters you can set a configuration option. Note: this will return the hash with string keys, not symbol keys.

```
#controller and action are parameters that are always permitter by default, but you need to add it in this config.
config.always_permitted_parameters = %w( controller action param_1 param_2)
```

Now you can access the params like:

```
def do_something_with_params
  params.slice("param_1", "param_2").to_h
end
```

Note that now the keys are strings and not symbols.

Hope this helps you to understand the root of your issue.

Source: [eileen.codes](http://eileencodes.com/posts/actioncontroller-parameters-now-returns-an-object-instead-of-a-hash/)

Comment: but this class, namely `ActionController::Parameters`, is a subclass of `Hash`, and the latter has a method `values`.

Comment: Not actually, that's why there is a `to_h` method in that class

Comment: try `params = ActionController::Parameters.new; params.values` to see that you do not need `to_h` here.

Comment: mmm it starts to make sense... lol may be related to rails version?

Comment: I'm running rails 5.0 beta1, tried adding .to_h on the param, but it gives me an empty hash

Comment: it is because you need to whitelist the params, please read carefully the answer. But you can still use `to_unsafe_h ` and avoid whitelisting

Comment: Please check the answer again, now I found the root of your issue. Hope it helps you

Answer (score 19):

Since Rails 5, params are of class 'ActionController::Parameters'

If you do params.to_h you will get the following error.

```
*** ActionController::UnfilteredParameters Exception: unable to convert 
unpermitted parameters to hash
```

You can do as follows to permit all the params and get as Hash format:

```
parameters = params.permit(params.keys).to_h
```

*"But beware of using this! You are permitting all the params which may include unknown params that can harm your code."*

Answer (score 2):

I think what's happening is the following:

In a console you are working with a simple hash called `attributes`. As a hash the `attributes` parameter in the console has [a valid instance method](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-values) called `values`.

In your rails app the params hash is not a simple hash any more. It is an instance of the `ActionController::Parameters` class. As an instance of that class it does not have an instance method called `values`, but it does have [an instance method called](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-to_h) `to_h` & `to_unsafe_h`, which would accomplish your goals. After calling `to_h` on your parameters you can call the `values` method.

Comment: but the class `ActionController::Parameters`, is a subclass of `Hash`, and the latter has a method `values`.

Comment: More specifically, try in a console
    `params = ActionController::Parameters.new({line_item: ActionController::Parameters.new({line_item_attributes_attributes: ActionController::Parameters.new})});
    attributes = params[:line_item][:line_item_attributes_attributes] || {};
    puts attributes.class;
    attributes.values`

Comment: true... you can also simply run `ActionController::Parameters.method_defined? :values` and you'll see that values is a valid method... now I'm stumped

Comment: @tillmo diving into the Ruby though you can try this with your `params` variable: `params.kind_of? Hash #=> true`, but then try `params.instance_of? Hash #=> false` So params is a kind of hash, but not an instance of hash... why would that be?

Comment: Looking in Rails 5, Parameters no longer inherits from Hash (via HashWithIndifferentAccess), but they did add :values as a delegate method, so it should still work... Here is the Rails 5 [code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L108) vs. the Rails 4 [code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9ab2d030209d9608a6c866d83210f5b3b7d2319e/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L108)

Comment: I'm indeed using Rails 5, however when I do  attributes = params[:line_item][:line_item_attributes_attributes].to_h it becomes an empty hash.

Comment: You have to call `to_h` on the safe version of the params, i.e. `my_params = params.permit(:line_item).require(:product_attribute_id)`, basically wherever you whitelisted your params in the controller... otherwise you have to call `to_unsafe_h` on params... or you can probably run this: `params.permit!.to_h`, but that will permanently de-whitelist your params hash, which you shouldn't want... better to work with a safe version of the params hash

Comment: And... `:values` should still work since it was added as a delegate method in Rails 5.

Answer (score 0):

Word to the wise: if you're using `link_to_sorted` from the [sorted](https://github.com/mynameisrufus/sorted) gem it breaks views in Rails 5.