# Passing a hash into a link is not encoded

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have a link like this where params[:q] is a hash.

```
<%= link_to "My Path", slides_path(query:params[:q]) %>
```

And to see what's going on in the view write it out

```
<%= params[:q] %>
```

<%= params[:q] %> will correctly write out the hash as

```
{:foo => :bar ,:goo => :bar}
```

But the url is encoded as

```
"q"=>"foo=bar&goo=bar"
```

So when the link is clicked the parameters are inferred as a string.

I want to pass the hash to the link and then have the controller get the hash back. Is there a simple way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Actual url format href="/slides?q=foo%3D%26bar%3D%26goo%3D%26bar3D3"

Comment: Have you tried anything like `URI.decode(params)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rails 5 `params` isn't a subclass of `Hash` anymore (for security reasons).
See: [Rails 5: unable to retrieve hash values from parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949505/rails-5-unable-to-retrieve-hash-values-from-parameter)

To overcome this you can call `to_unsafe_h`.
It'll turn params in a proper hash and thus properly encoded it in the url.

```
<%= link_to "My Path", slides_path(query: params.to_unsafe_h[:q]) %>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.