# undefined method `map' api request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, faraday, mashape

I followed tutorial how to integrate 3rd party api with a ruby on rails but I get an error

> undefined method `map' for
>
> {"number"=>12} permitted: false>:ActionController::Parameters

which points to **request.rb**

```
query_string = query.map{|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join("&")
```

Full code

**recipes_controller.rb**

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @tag = query.fetch(:tags, 'all')
    @refresh_params = refresh_params
    @recipes, @errors = Spoonacular::Recipe.random(query, clear_cache)
  end

  def show
    @recipe = Spoonacular::Recipe.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
   def query
     params.permit(:query).fetch(:query, {})
   end

  def clear_cache
    params[:clear_cache].present?
  end

  def refresh_params
    refresh = { clear_cache: true }
    refresh.merge!({ query: query }) if query.present?
    refresh
  end
end
```

**app/services/spoonacular/recipes.rb**

```
module Spoonacular
  class Recipe < Base
    attr_accessor :aggregate_likes,
                  :dairy_free,
                  :gluten_free,
                  :id,
                  :image,
                  :ingredients,
                  :instructions,
                  :ready_in_minutes,
                  :title,
                  :vegan,
                  :vegetarian

    MAX_LIMIT = 12
    CACHE_DEFAULTS = { expires_in: 7.days, force: false }

    def self.random(query = {}, clear_cache)
      cache = CACHE_DEFAULTS.merge({ force: clear_cache })
      response = Spoonacular::Request.where('recipes/random', cache, query.merge({ number: MAX_LIMIT }))
      recipes = response.fetch('recipes', []).map { |recipe| Recipe.new(recipe) }
      [ recipes, response[:errors] ]
    end

    def self.find(id)
      response = Spoonacular::Request.get("recipes/#{id}/information", CACHE_DEFAULTS)
      Recipe.new(response)
    end

    def initialize(args = {})
      super(args)
      self.ingredients = parse_ingredients(args)
      self.instructions = parse_instructions(args)
    end

    def parse_ingredients(args = {})
      args.fetch("extendedIngredients", []).map { |ingredient| Ingredient.new(ingredient) }
    end

    def parse_instructions(args = {})
      instructions = args.fetch("analyzedInstructions", [])
      if instructions.present?
        steps = instructions.first.fetch("steps", [])
        steps.map { |instruction| Instruction.new(instruction) }
      else
        []
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**app/services/spoonacular/base.rb**

```
module Spoonacular
  class Base
    attr_accessor :errors

    def initialize(args = {})
      args.each do |name, value|
        attr_name = name.to_s.underscore
        send("#{attr_name}=", value) if respond_to?("#{attr_name}=")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**app/services/spoonacular/request.rb**

```
module Spoonacular
  class Request
    class << self
      def where(resource_path, cache, query = {}, options = {})
        response, status = get_json(resource_path, cache, query)
        status == 200 ? response : errors(response)
      end

      def get(id, cache)
        response, status = get_json(id, cache)
        status == 200 ? response : errors(response)
      end

      def errors(response)
        error = { errors: { status: response["status"], message: response["message"] } }
        response.merge(error)
      end

      def get_json(root_path, cache, query = {})
        query_string = query.map{|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join("&")
        path = query.empty?? root_path : "#{root_path}?#{query_string}"
        response =  Rails.cache.fetch(path, expires_in: cache[:expires_in], force: cache[:force]) do
          api.get(path)
        end
        [JSON.parse(response.body), response.status]
      end

      def api
        Connection.api
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**app/services/spoonacular/connection.rb**

```
require 'faraday'
require 'json'
module Spoonacular
  class Connection
    BASE = 'https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.mashape.com'

    def self.api
      Faraday.new(url: BASE) do |faraday|
        faraday.response :logger
        faraday.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
        faraday.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        faraday.headers['X-Mashape-Key'] ='key'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Include paths to these files in your question. 
Also did you try to move `Request` under `Spoonacular::Recipe` namespace? And if it shouldnt be there did you try to refer to global scope with `::Request.where(...)`?

Comment: I bet path to `request.rb` contains `/spoonacular/recipe/` so rails tries to resolve `Request` constant based on that

Comment: So did `::Request.where(...)` work? Also I would suggest to move `request.rb` and `connection.rb` to `app/services/spoonacular/` namespace. In that case you call it like `Spoonacular::Request`

Comment: You mean like this? 
response = ::Request.where('recipes/random', cache, query.merge({ number: MAX_LIMIT }))
I moved all files to spoonacular folder and now I get error --> Unable to autoload constant Spoonacular::Request

Comment: Did you encircle `class Request` with `module Spoonacular` after you move `request.rb`?

Comment: Yes, I did it now. Now I get same error as before --> undefined method `map' for <ActionController::Parameters {"number"=>12} permitted: false>:ActionController::Parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 separate errors here.

> uninitialized constant Spoonacular::Recipe::Request

This one you can fix by explicitly setting top-level scope for `Request` class:

```
::Request.where(...)
```

It applies if you keep `Request` file in `app/spoonacular/request.rb`. But I suggest to move it to `app/services/spoonacular/` where all your other `spoonacular` related classes are. So in this case you need to encircle `class Request` in `module Spoonacular`. After that you can call it like that:

```
Spoonacular::Request.where(...)
```

Same goes for class `Connection`.

[SO answer about scope resolution operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032844/ruby-what-does-prefix-do)

---

> undefined method `map' for {"number"=>12} permitted:
>   false>:ActionController::Parameters

This one comes from private `query` method in `recipes_controller.rb`. `params` is `ActionController::Parameters` object and in order to retrieve values from it you need to permit them first:

```
def query
  params.permit(:query).to_h
end
```

Now it should return `Hash` object.

[Here is detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949505/rails-5-unable-to-retrieve-hash-values-from-parameter) on SO about that

[RubyOnRails Guide about strong params](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)

Comment: I made changes like you said, but still same problem. I updated question.

Comment: @Kristis I dont really see what you have changed

Comment: I made changes in controller query method and in recipe.rb file self.random method. Also, I encircled connection and request class in module Spoonacular.

Comment: @Kristis There is still old version of `query` method in your question.

Comment: @Kristis Check out [RubyOnRails Guide about strong params](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters). It will help you understand your second issue

Comment: I made query permitted with this code --> params.permit(query: {}) but getting same error --> undefined method `map' for <ActionController::Parameters {"number"=>12} permitted: true>:ActionController::Parameters

Comment: @Kristis Try to convert it to Hash object with `query.to_h`

Comment: @MartinZinovsky I'm following the same tutorial (apparently) and getting the same errors.  Adding `to_h` gives the error: `unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash`