# Rails how to use where method for search or return all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, search, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to do a search with multiple attributes for `Address` at my Rails API.

I want to search by state, city and/or street. But user doesn't need to send all attributes, he can search only by city if he wants.

So I need something like this: if the condition exists search by condition or return all results of this condition.

**Example:**

search request: `street = 'some street', city = '', state = ''`

How can I use rails `where` method to return all if some condition is nil?

I was trying something like this, but I know that `||:all` doesn't work, it's just to illustrate what I have in mind.:

```
def get_address
  address = Adress.where(
    state: params[:state] || :all,
    city: params[:city] || :all,
    street: params[:street] || :all)
end
```

It's possible to do something like that? Or maybe there is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a more elegant solution using some simple hash manipulation:

```
def filter_addesses(scope = Adress.all)
  # slice takes only the keys we want
  # compact removes nil values
  filters = params.permit(:state, :city, :street).to_h.compact
  scope = scope.where(filters) if filters.any?
  scope
end
```

Comment: Thank you max, I just edited your answer to follow [this new rails 5 changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949505/rails-5-unable-to-retrieve-hash-values-from-parameter)

Comment: You are right but your solution was a bit over the top. Simply changing slice to permit fixes the issue.

Comment: I think that `params.to_h` it's also needed, as the first answer of the link above says: *Rails 5 ActionController::Parameters now returns an Object instead of a Hash*

Comment: You're right again. `ActionController::Parameters.new(state: 'VT', city: 'Montpelier').permit(:state, :city, :street).to_h.compact
` does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Once you're passing a column to `where`, there isn't an option that means "on second thought don't filter by this". Instead, you can construct the relation progressively:

```
def get_address
  addresses = Address.all
  addresses = addresses.where(state: params[:state]) if params[:state]
  addresses = addresses.where(city: params[:city]) if params[:city]
  addresses = addresses.where(street: params[:street]) if params[:street]
  addresses
end
```

Comment: This pattern does not keep your controller Skinny.  Over time, additional parameters may get added which will clutter up your controller even more.  Consider the Search Object Pattern instead and encapsulate this logic into a Ruby PORO.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using the [Searchlight](https://github.com/nathanl/searchlight) gem.   It solves precisely the problem you're describing.  Instead of cluttering up your controllers, pass your search `params` to a Searchlight class.  This will DRY up your code and keep your controllers skinny too.  You'll not only solve your problem, but you'll have more maintainable code too.  Win-win!

So in your case, you'd make an AddressSearch class:

```
class AddressSearch < Searchlight::Search

  # This is the starting point for any chaining we do, and it's what
  # will be returned if no search options are passed.
  # In this case, it's an ActiveRecord model.
  def base_query
    Address.all # or `.scoped` for ActiveRecord 3
  end

  # A search method.
  def search_state
    query.where(state: options[:state])
  end

  # Another search method.
  def search_city
    query.where(city: options[:city])
  end
  # Another search method.
  def search_street
    query.where(street: options[:street])
  end
end
```

Then in your controller you just need to search by passing in your search params into the class above:

```
AddressSearch.new(params).results
```

One nice thing about this gem is that any extraneous parameters will be scrubbed automatically by Searchlight.  Only the State, City, and Street params will be used.

Comment: Thank you for this! I think will help me a lot